# How to populate select base on another select with JSON and Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to loop the value from JSON file on select option,
this is my JSON file look

```
[{
    "vehicle": "car1",
    "type": [
      {"name" : "BMW",
      "details" : [{
        "color" : "red",
        "price" : "50000"
        },
        {
          "color" : "blue",
          "price" : "51000"
          }]}
    ]},
  {
    "vehicle": "car2",
    "type": [
      {"name" : "Lambo",
      "details" : [{
        "color" : "green",
        "price" : "150000"
        },
        {
          "color" : "yellow",
          "price" : "151000"
          }]}
    ]}
]
```

and i want to populate the value in 2 select,
this is my code i use loop for that

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  select1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <option>${data[i].vehicle}</option>
  `)

  for (j = 0; j < data[i].type.length; j++) {
  
    for (k = 0; k < data[i].type[j].details.length; k++) {
  
      select2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <option">${data[j].type[j].details[k].color}</option>
      `)
    }
  }
```

}

my objective is my first select option :

- car1
- car2

and second select option is :

- red / green
- blue / yellow

base on the first select, so if i select car 1 and in the select2 only show red and blue,
and in my code in the select2 is showing 4 item,

can anybody help me with this? thank you

```js
 var json_obj =  [{
        "vehicle": "car1",
        "type": [
          {"name" : "BMW",
          "details" : [{
            "color" : "red",
            "price" : "50000"
            },
            {
              "color" : "blue",
              "price" : "51000"
              }]}
        ]},
      {
        "vehicle": "car2",
        "type": [
          {"name" : "Lambo",
          "details" : [{
            "color" : "green",
            "price" : "150000"
            },
            {
              "color" : "yellow",
              "price" : "151000"
              }]}
        ]}
    ];


function apply_change(data) {
    var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      select1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <option>${data[i].vehicle}</option>
      `)
    
      for (j = 0; j < data[i].type.length; j++) {
      
        for (k = 0; k < data[i].type[j].details.length; k++) {
      
          select2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
            <option">${data[j].type[j].details[k].color}</option>
          `)
        }
      }

  }
}

apply_change(json_obj);
```

```html
select 1: <select id="select1"></select>
select 2: <select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: Only set the content of the select2 after the user has changed the value of select1 (add an event listener on select1).

Comment: take a color array; initialize this array on choosing car options. push color to this array by iterating your object with specific conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited your code to give desired output you can also check my jsfiddle solution. [Select onchange - pure javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/efo169rm/)

```js
 var json_obj =  [{
        "vehicle": "car1",
        "type": [
          {"name" : "BMW",
          "details" : [{
            "color" : "red",
            "price" : "50000"
            },
            {
              "color" : "blue",
              "price" : "51000"
              }]}
        ]},
      {
        "vehicle": "car2",
        "type": [
          {"name" : "Lambo",
          "details" : [{
            "color" : "green",
            "price" : "150000"
            },
            {
              "color" : "yellow",
              "price" : "151000"
              }]}
        ]}
    ];


var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
LoadSelect1();

function LoadSelect1() {
  for (i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++) {
     select1.options.add(new Option(json_obj[i].vehicle, json_obj[i].vehicle));
  }
  LoadSelect2(json_obj[0].vehicle);
}

function LoadSelect2(selectedvalue) {
  console.log(selectedvalue);
  select2.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++) {
    if (json_obj[i].vehicle == selectedvalue) {
      for (j = 0; j < json_obj[i].type.length; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < json_obj[i].type[j].details.length; k++) {
          select2.options.add(new Option(json_obj[i].type[j].details[k].color, json_obj[i].type[j].details[k].color));
          }
       }
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
   select 1: <select id="select1" onchange="LoadSelect2(this.value)"></select>
   select 2: <select id="select2"></select>
```